# Add Custom JS to Modal Insert Widget Admin Form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, widget, modal

I am wanting to do custom javascript to manipulate the Widget Options when adding a widget (using the WYSIWYG editor) in the Admin panel.

I have found that the layout handle `adminhtml_widget_index` is being loaded via AJAX to get that content, however, I have noticed that any script tags in my template file are being removed.

For demonstration purposes the phtml file I am using looks like

```
// Module_Vendor::test.phtml
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Template $block */
?>
<h2>Modal windows strip custom js...</h2>
<script>
    alert('Just kidding, JAVASCRIPT works in modals');
</script>
```

I have the `<h2>` tag showing on the widget modal form, but looking at the source there is no script tag.

Looking further into how the widget renders, using the `\Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget` class, there is a `protected $_formScripts` array that might be used with a plugin which could solve the issue, however I'm wondering if there is another way to render custom javascript on the Insert Widget modal form?

If anyone has any useful information, I'd be delighted to hear it.

Thanks in advance!

As a side note there is an initialisation of the wysiwyg widget javascript component which is added as a string to the `$_formScripts` array, which doesn't seem like best practice, so even if using the `$_formScripts` array is how we should do it, if you could provide an example of how, that would also be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the test template (I should've tested it before posting) the JS alert is showing as expected. I had specific JS issues with the other JS I was trying to render, but the source still doesn't show the script tag, which is what led me to think this is where it was broken.

This could be a good place for custom widget JS discussion, or determining best practice, but I'm going to mark this as answered.

Edit: To be clear, adding a custom block to the `admin_widget_index` layout file actually did render the custom javascript, there is just some tricky preprocessing that Magento does to script elements, where the JS is loaded anonymously... I'm not actually sure how it works, but the JS is running, so I didn't have to use the _formScripts array at all.

An example layout xml file looks like

```
<!-- vendor/mycompany/module-modify-widget-options/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_widget_index.xml -->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="root">
        <block class="\Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Module_Vendor::test.phtml" name="test_edit_modal"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</layout>
```

Comment: Also a little bonus, the widget options are loaded with a separate LoadOptions action, so in order to modify the options with custom JS I had to trigger a custom event, then in my custom widget js I could listen and modify the data AFTER the widget options were loaded

Comment: could you edit the answer to show how you added the js to the  `_formScripts`